# Cannot use index access type with T[Key extends keyof T]

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, keyof

I found myself with very often working with arrays like

```
[
{key1: val1, key2: value2, key3: val3},
{key1: val1, key2: value2, key3: val3},
{key1: val1, key2: value2, key3: val3}]
```

where I want to transform this into a dictionary/map, e.g.

```
[val1FromFirstElement]: {key2: val2, key3, val3},
[val1FromSecondElement]: {key2: val2, key3, val3},
[val1ThirdElement]: {key2: val2, key3, val3}}
```

Often I use a reduce, but it makes the code busy. I want to write a generic helper, where we can ensure the array we are mapping over expects the key we want to index on (in the case above, key1).

```
function toDictionary<T, Key extends keyof T> (array: T[], key: Key) {
  return array.reduce((prev, cur: T) => {
      return{...prev, ...{[cur[key]]: cur}};
  }, {})
}
```

The problem is that `[cur[key]]` won't compile stating `A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.`

I believe an index access type can only be `number | string | symbol`, but I don't see why I should have to specify anything else as typescript should know that a key type can only be one of these types? Right?

Hoping someone can show me where my misunderstanding is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific error you are getting is because `T` in `toDictionary` is unconstrained which makes `Key` indeterminate.  In other words, as it stands, your function would accept *any* type for T.

For example, try calling your function as `toDictionary([3,4,5], "")`.  What you'll see is that the first parameter passes fine.  Why? because `T[]` can be *any* array since `T` is unconstrained.  The second parameter generates an error because the only `keyof` types for the elements in array of numbers like `[3,4,5]` are the prototype properties for any number, like, `toString`, `toFixed`, etc.  And, so, actually, `toDictionary([3,4,5], "toString")` would pass your typing just fine, even though it's not what you want.

The problem is that what you really want is `T` to only be types that actually have keys, like in the example you gave of `{key1: val1, key2: value2, key3: val3}`.  So you need to constrain T somehow.  Constraining it to be `extends Record<string,any>` would do the trick as now `T` needs to be some object indexed by strings (as in the examples you gave).  For example, this typing would work for the example you gave:

```js
function toDictionary<T extends Record<string,any>, Key extends keyof T> (array: T[], key: Key) {
  return array.reduce((prev, cur: T) => {
      return{...prev, ...{[cur[key]]: cur}};
  }, {})
}
```

And you'll see that the contrived `toDictionary([3,4,5], "toString")` example above, now fails properly.

You could also be even more explicit in your constraint, for example `T extends {key1:any, key2:any, key3: any}` to restrict to just objects with that form.  That really depends on how you want to use it.

(FWIW, it's not clear to me what you expect the behavior to be if the array you pass has multiple items with the same value for `key1`.  Your current function will just overwrite any previous values with the last one in the iteration; that may not be what you want.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm a little confused as T is an array, not a mapping of key-values (which a Record is)... so why would T extend Record<string, any>? In fact the output of my function is pretty much a Record<K, T> is it not?

To your second paragraph, you make a good point which I hadn't considered.  toDictionary implicitly assumes key1's value (val1) is unique for each element in the array. I guess there isn't a way to enforce that through types.

Comment: Actually the way you have it defined `T` is not inferred as an array.  Your `array` parameter is typed as `T[]` so it is an array of `T`'s and therefore `T` gets inferred as the _elements_ of that array.

Comment: In terms of enforcing a unique key for a given element in an array of objects, there is no single type that can do it, but you can do it via a helper/builder function along the lines of `insertElement(array, newElement)` that returns a new array with the new element in order to construct your array.  That function can be typed checked.  If you need more help with that, I suggest posting a new question with an example of how you want it to work, since that's different than this question.

Comment: ahh yes,, you're right -I take an array of Ts. T itself is not an array. OK. So now we agree T is NOT an array,  I still don't see why `T extend Record<string, any>`. The only thing place I can see types T and Record would be the function return type, which could be `Record<keytype, T>`.

Comment: You need to constrain `T` in some way that `keyof T` resolves to a type that can be used to index your return type (e.g., `string | number | symbol | any`).  So the question is what constraint to use. Well, the example you gave of what you pass in as `array` that satisfies `T[]` is an array of things like `{key1: val1, key2: value2, key3: val3}`.  Those are all basically examples of `Record<string, any>` so constraining `T` to that means that your `array` parameter key any array of objects that are indexed with a string, and therefore `keyof T` will now have to be a string.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to explain this a little more since it seems to be the source of confusion.

Comment: Thank you @sam256. Your edited answer made a lot of sense. Your updated answer led me to discover object keys can only be `string` in JavaScript, while in TypeScript they can be `string | number | symbol`.

Comment: something new that has come from working with this - can I avoid having to specify the key as a parameter in both type template and input. see
`toDictionary<MyType[], keyA>(arrayOfMyType, "keyA")`
it feels 'wrong' to have to write keyA in both places.

Comment: Typescript should be able to infer both type parameters. Can you post a complete example of the code you are trying  to get to work?